# ¿Cómo hago clustering en 3D?

Tags: cluster

El problema es el siguiente:
Parto de una variable con 3 dimensiones (1460,2880,3), como si fuera una imagen RGB. Tengo que agrupar cada punto X,Y,Z (es otro espacio tridimensional pero para el ejemplo vale) mediante el algoritmo de fuzzy c means en Python. He visto que hay una librería disponible, skfuzzy, que ya me he instalado, pero los datos de entrada deben ser de 2 dimensiones. 
No tiene sentido trabajar cada componente ya que tengo que agrupar las 3 dimensiones. 
La documentación de skfuzzy tampoco me está ayudando mucho, y no he visto en internet que se pueda hacer clustering con este algoritmo en 3 dimensiones. Sí lo he visto con k-means creo, aunque no sé si en Python. 
¿Tendría que hacerme yo una función de clustering fuzzy c-means 3D? Y de ser así, ¿alguna ayuda para ello?

Comment: Los algoritmos de clustering por lo general son agnósticos a la cantidad de dimensiones dado que esta cantidad varía considerablemente desde una aplicación a otra; de hecho 2 dimensiones resulta ser poco para la mayoría de los datos multi dimensionales que se ocupan hoy. Puedes explicar de que librería obtuviste ese método que intentas ocupar? Dado que leyendo la documentación probablemente entendamos a que se refiere la restricción de 2-dimensionalidad.

Comment: Hola, tiene usted razón, simplemente cuando llamo a la función fuzz.cluster.cmeans de skfuzzy de Python, le tengo que pasar en mi caso los colores RGB pero redimensionados, es decir, una matriz de (3,M) donde cada fila se corresponde con el valor de cada componente R, G o B, y M indica el nº de píxeles de la imagen. Pero la agrupación en N-Dimensiones sería idéntica. Solo que en vez de pasarle una matriz (3,N), sería una matriz (M,N)